# How to download a video file into browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, video, youtube-api

I made the routes below in express to download a video from youtube, but the video file goes into my project folder and it is not downloaded into the browser. It's like it works only in localhost.
This is my project folder:

```
node_modules
src
  -app.js
static
  -index.html
  -styles.css
package.json
'THE FILE DOWNLOADED'
```

This is the code i made

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const fs = require('fs')
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')
const youtube = require('simple-youtube-api')

router.post('/downloadByUrl', async (req, res) => {
  let url = req.body.url
  await downloadVideo(url)
  return res.redirect('/')
})

router.post('/downloadByName', async (req, res) => {
  let videoName = req.body.videoName
  let youtubeClient = new youtube('MY YOUTUBE API KEY')

  await youtubeClient.searchVideos(videoName, 1)
  .then(results => {
    downloadVideo('https://youtu.be/' + results[0].id)
  })
  .catch(console.log)

  return res.redirect('/')
})

function downloadVideo(URL) {
  let videoReadableStream = ytdl(URL)

  ytdl.getInfo(URL, (err, info) => {
    let title = info.title.replace('|', '').toString('ascii')
    let stream = videoReadableStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(title + '.mp4'))
    stream.on('finish', () => {
      console.log('Finished')
    })
  })
}

module.exports = router
```

I want to host my website so i want to make possible the download of the file into the 'download' section of the browser.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why using `videoReadableStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream` then?

Comment: You need to do this on the front end (the code being ran in thee browser) rather than on the backend (the code being run on your server).

Comment: What should I do? @LawrenceCherone

Comment: you want to aim for `videoReadableStream.pipe(res)`, but be aware proxying massive amounts of data through your host is not ideal.

Comment: if you set the Header `Content-Disposition: attachment` does that do what you need?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I solved using this method but I can't use res.redirect('/') after that

Comment: you can't do both, its unclear what are you trying to achieve, why would a download redirect after?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone because I want to download it and then to redirect to the main page (so it will clear all the input fields). I have seen that your .pipe(res) method doesn't work in Safari browser... Do you know a solution?